# Median-of-Medians proof for time complexity

Tags: selection-problem

[Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Proof_of_O(n)_running_time), that from the formula
$$
T(n) \leq T(n/5) + T(n\cdot7/10) + c \cdot n
$$

one can "easily" show using induction that

$$
T(n) \leq 10 \cdot c \cdot n
$$

I am, as it seems, not so smart. So, can anyone tell me how to show this using induction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

Comment: This analysis was the exact reason I wrote up https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/83650/68251.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you got the base covered, here is the inductive step:
$$
T(n) \leq T(n/5) + T(7n/10) + cn \leq 10c(n/5) + 10c(7n/10) + cn = 10cn.
$$
(Cheating a bit, since $n$ isn't necessarily divisible by 10; but that's a problem in the recurrence.)

You can also just apply the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: How do you drop the $T(.)$ at the second inequality?

Comment: Using the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Ah I see, but how do you even come up with such a hypothesis in the first place? I'm not good at coming up with a *possible* answer and then going backwards to show that the *possible* answer is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: You get better with experience... Here, we can assume a induction hypothesis of the form $T(n) \leq Mn$, and check for which values of $M$ the inductive step goes through. It turns out that $M=10c$ works.

Answer (score 1):

I am basically just paraphrasing the steps I've outlined here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/83650/68251.

This is assuming the base case is $T(n) \leq c$ when $n < 5$.

#### Claim

$T(n) \leq 10\cdot c\cdot n$

#### Proof by Induction (on $n$)

**Basis**: $n < 5 \implies T(n) \leq c < 10\cdot c < 10\cdot c \cdot n$

**Induction**: Assume the claim holds for any $n' < n$, we then have

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &\leq cn + T(n/5) + T(7n/10)\\
&\leq cn + 10c\cdot n /5 + 10c\cdot 7n /10\\
&= cn + 10c\cdot 9n /10\\
&= 10 \cdot c \cdot n & \square\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Where does the basis come from?

Comment: From the basis in https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/83650/68251. When $n < 5$ we know that $T(n)$ will resolve to some constant because we cannot recurse anymore. This is because $T(5/5) = T(1) = c$. Similarly if we had the recurrence $T(n) = T(n/9) + T(3n/4) + cn$, then the basis would have to be for $n < 9$ for the same reason.

Comment: I don't see why we shouldn't be able to recurse anymore.
If $n=4$, there is still $T(4 \cdot 7/10)$.

Comment: You need a base case to your recurrence, or else you will recurse indefinitely. I have chosen the base case to be $n < 5$. It also doesn't particularly matter that I chose 5. We only need the claim to hold for all $n$ greater than some $n_0$ to show $T(n) = O(n)$.

Comment: But with the same method, I could also prove the exact opposite $T(n) \geq 10 \cdot cn$

Basis: $n < 5 => T(n) \geq 10\cdot cn \geq 10\cdot c \geq c$
And then use the same induction steps with $\geq$ insted of $\leq$

I guess I just don't understand it, but thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: For the base case $T(n) \leq c$ when $n < 5$ you could not prove that. I added this detail more explicitly in the answer.